# Combining lists into tuples in list comprehension

Tags: erlang

```
A = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6]].
B = [ [a,b,c],[d,e,f]].
```

The output should be:

```
[ [{1,a},{2,b},{3,c}],[{4,d},{5,e},{6,f}]].
```

This is what I have got so far.

Input:    [ [{Y} || Y<-X ] || X<-A].
Output:    [[{1},{2},{3}],[{4},{5},{6}]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
[lists:zip(LA, LB) || {LA, LB} <- lists:zip(A, B)].
```

You need to zip both lists to be able to work with their elements together.

Comment: I am not aware of this zip fucntion. How does it work?

Comment: lists:zip* functions traverse lists of equal length in parallel. More info: http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#zip-2